# Why "Go to implementation(s)" shows also the intefrace file itself?

Tags: phpstorm

In phpStorm 2023.2 In laravel/php app I use DbRepositoryInterface class with different implementations, like :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\DbRepositoryInterface;
...

class BotManController extends Controller
{
    protected DbRepositoryInterface $dbRepositoryInterface;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbRepositoryInterface = \App::make(DbRepositoryInterface::class);
        ...
    }

    public function index(string $hashedLink = '')
    {
        ...
        if ( ! empty($currentUserQuizRequest['quiz_category_id'])) {
            $quizCategory = $this->dbRepositoryInterface->getQuizCategory($currentUserQuizRequest['quiz_category_id']);
        }

        $this->siteName = $this->dbRepositoryInterface::getSettingsValue('site_name');
        ...
```

Function "Go to implementation(s)" shows 1 implementation file and the intefrace file itself :

[image]

I expected to see only  1 implementation file and no the intefrace file, but I see last?

Is it some option I need to configure ?

Comment: Looks like, it is a form of this bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39153/Go-to-implementation-goes-to-declaration